# Is there a way to Update a firebase document field at a specific time?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a car parking app in flutter, and I would like to change a bool value in a Firestore document at a specific time that can be found on a timestamp in another document.
To be precise, The user will book a parking space and select an endtime(this would be the timestamp). After the booking process is successful, there is a bool value (inUse: false), the bool value is set to true so that the parking space is not shown on the app because its in use. However, at the endtime I would like to change the bool value to false to show that the parking space is now free.

This is what the document for the parking space looks like.

[image: A screenshot of the parking space document]

This below is what the document for the order looks like (where we can find the end timestamp).

[image: A screenshot of the order document]

So, I am looking for a cloud function or be able to create a scheduled job upon a successful booking to update the bool inUse to false at a set time defined by the end timestap that we can find in the order document.

Comment: There's nothing built into Firestore for this, but you can build it with Cloud Functions and Cloud Tasks.